# ArrayList in servlet with previous values

Tags: servlets

I declared an arraylist in doPost method and I passed it to the another servlet page. The problem is arraylist contains old values for every new request.

Here I am providing the code

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest reqst,HttpServletResponse res)
{ 

   ArrayList<String> tabledata=new ArrayList<String>(); 
   Calculation(tabledata); //Which adds some strings to the tabledata 
   HttpSession hs=reqst.getSession(); 
   hs.setAttribute("tabledata",tabledata); 
   res.sendRedirect("nextpage")// redirecting to another servlet page 
}
```

I want the arraylist to contain only present request data. But it is storing all the previous request's data also.

Comment: Why don't you store this data on the request rather than the session, then forward rather than redirect?

Comment: plz can you explain how can we store data on the request.

Answer (score 0):

You could store this data on the request not the session, then forward rather than redirect.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest reqst,HttpServletResponse res)
{ 
    ArrayList<String> tabledata=new ArrayList<String>(); 
    Calculation(tabledata); //Which adds some strings to the tabledata 
    reqst.setAttribute("tabledata",tabledata); 
    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("nextpage").forward(request, response);
}
```